# Tools to investigate how DNS over TLS/HTTPS work / how resolve / if work correctly/ how establish tunnels etc

Tags: dns, ssl, certificates, https

- DoT DNS over TLS https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7858
- DoH DNS over HTTPs https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8484

(nice explanation: https://blog.cloudflare.com/dns-encryption-explained/ - TL;DR- port tcp/853)

Traditionally for DNS over udp/53 we could use `dig` to investigate resolution.

I would like to investigate not only resolution, but also quality of encryption layer of connection (i.e. certificate used etc).

Using what tool/tools/command would you recommend investigation of Encrypted DNS resolution (DoT , DoH), including typical `dig` staff and used encryption certificates?
(is there sth better then just combination with `wireshark` or `openssl` ?)

Comment: What operating system are you using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [dog](https://github.com/ogham/dog). dog is a command-line DNS client.

From the README:

> Protocol options
>
> ```
> -U, --udp                Use the DNS protocol over UDP
> -T, --tcp                Use the DNS protocol over TCP
> -S, --tls                Use the DNS-over-TLS protocol
> -H, --https              Use the DNS-over-HTTPS protocol
> ```